# Trying to evaluate a limit, but apparently my answer is wrong?

Tags: calculus, limits

So I was trying to work out a question for my calculus class that involved a limit. I got to an answer that seems correct as far as I can tell, but when I submitted it, the website that we use for homework said that it was incorrect.
Here is the question, and my attempt to solve it:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{t}\cos t\ dt}{x^2}
$$
$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{t}\cos t \ dt=0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^+}x^2=0$, therefore the original limit is the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$ and L'Hôpital's rule applies to it.
$$
\implies\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{t}\cos t\ dt}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{x}\cos x}{2x}
$$
Again this is the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$, so L'Hôpital's rule can be used once more:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{x}\cos x}{2x}=\frac{1}{4}\lim_{x \to 0^+} \left(\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}}-2\sqrt{x}\sin x  \right)=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{0^+}-0 \right)=\infty
$$
I gave $\infty$ as my answer, but the website says that it's wrong, so I'm not sure what else to do. I even checked websites like Wolfram Alpha, which got the same answer as me, and Desmos where the graph of the function in the limit also appears to approach infinity from $0^+$.
I'd appreciate any help or advice, because at this point I'm not sure where else to turn.

EDIT:
Okay so I just tried submitting my answer again, *the exact same answer,* and for some reason *now* it marked it as correct.
At least things got resolved... ‍♀‍

Comment: My only guesses at the moment is that the question is technically ill-defined:

$$\int_0^x f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$$

as an expression doesn't really make sense (integrating over $x \in (0,x)$?), though

$$\int_0^x f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$$

does make sense. That, or depending on the format of the answers presented to you, it expected you to say "the limit does not exist" instead of equaling infinity.

Comment: @PrincessEev You're absolutely right, I realized just now that I wrote the question down wrong in my post- thank you for pointing that out! As for the potential that they wanted me to put in that it doesn't exist- I did think about that too, but it actually says on the question to give $\infty$ as the answer if it equals infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your work was somewhat sloppy because you are **over-using** the variable $x$, I agree with the conclusion that the limit is $\infty$.

As $x \to 0^+$, from the Taylor series for $\cos(x)$, you always have that $\cos(x) > 1 - \dfrac{x^2}{2}.$

Therefore, you have that

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\int_0^x \sqrt{t}\cos(t)dt}{x^2} > 
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\int_0^x \sqrt{t}\left[1 - \dfrac{t^2}{2}\right]dt}{x^2}
$$

$$= \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\frac{2x^{3/2}}{3} - \frac{x^{7/2}}{7}}{x^2}$$

$$= \lim_{x \to 0^+} \left[ ~\frac{2}{3x^{1/2}} - \frac{x^{3/2}}{7} ~\right]. \tag1 $$

In (1) above, as $x \to 0^+,~$ the first term grows unbounded and the second term goes to $0$.  Therefore, the expression does grow unbounded.

Comment: thanks for the response! I'm glad to know I'm not going insane and someone else actually agrees with my answer haha :)
I also appreciate the constructive criticism in my work! I'm a bit unsure of what you mean by over-using $x$ though, could you elaborate?  (If you meant with the integration variable, then that completely makes sense- someone else pointed out my mistake as well and I fixed it pretty soon after)

Comment: @cdog Before you revised your posting, you had an expression that looked like $$\int_0^x \sqrt{x}\cos(x)$$ when what you intended was $$\int_0^x \sqrt{t}\cos(t)dt.$$  That is, you were over-using $x$ as both the upper limit of the range of integration and the integrand's dummy variable.  Also, you omitted the $dx$ from your integration expression.

Comment: Ah okay that completely makes sense, thanks for letting me know!